# In Powershell, I call a SQL query that returns 10 tables...how can I turn each table into its own variable?

Tags: sql, excel, windows, powershell

Below is my script. How can I write a loop that turns each table into variable like $DataSetTable0, $DataSetTable1, $DataSetTable2, etc.? I know I could do this manually but I can't figure out how to use a loop to do this. Any help is much appreciated!

```
    $SqlQuery1 = get-content "C:\Users\test\00_Master.sql" | Out-String;

    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery1
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

----Manual Way------
    $DataSetTable0 = $DataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: if you want to do something with each table you could do a foreach datatable in $DataSet.Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt. I ended up using...

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $DataSet.Tables.Count; $i++)
{
    New-Variable -Name "DataSetTable$i" -Value $DataSet.Tables[$i]

}
```